# addValue to Dataset in Scala and jfreechart

Tags: scala, jfreechart

There is a ListMap with the below values:

scala> **mx_sorted**

```
res30: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 10 -> 10, 15 -> 66, 20 -> 157, 25 -> 175, 30 -> 135, 35 -> 106, 40 -> 88, 45 -> 80, 50 -> 62, 55 -> 32, 60 -> 19, 65 -> 8, 70 -> 4, 75 -> 0, 80 -> 0)
```

scala> **mx_sorted.foreach(println)**

```
(0,0)
(5,1)
(10,10)
(15,66)
(20,157)
(25,175)
(30,135)
(35,106)
(40,88)
(45,80)
(50,62)
(55,32)
(60,19)
(65,8)
(70,4)
(75,0)
(80,0)
```

Created a DefaultCategoryDataset

```
val ds = new org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset
```

When I am trying to addvalues to this dataset, getting error.

scala> **mx_sorted.foreach{case(k,v) => ds.addValue(v,"UserAges",k)}**

```
<console>:41: error: overloaded method value addValue with alternatives:
  (x$1: Double,x$2: Comparable[_],x$3: Comparable[_])Unit <and>
  (x$1: Number,x$2: Comparable[_],x$3: Comparable[_])Unit
 cannot be applied to (Int, String, Int)
              mx_sorted.foreach{case(k,v) => ds.addValue(v,"UserAges",k)}
```

Kindly help in rectifying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast fix is `{case(k,v) => ds.addValue(v: Double, "UserAges", k: java.lang.Integer)}` (`java.lang.` isn't necessary and probably neither is `: Double`, I am just including it to make it more clear). The issue is that `Int` doesn't extend `Comparable` (because it corresponds to the primitive JVM `int` type), so it needs to be boxed to `java.lang.Integer` which does.